# Mean of absolute difference series of two random series, uniformy distributed?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose we have two series of 100 (or more) random numbers between 0 and 1. Naturally, the average of series 1 is close to 1/2, and the average of series 2 is also close to 1/2. (screenshot attached.)

Lets consider a new series 3 'abs diff' by taking the absolute difference of the two series:

abs diff = |series 1- series 2|.

Now the mean of the abs diff series is always close to 1/3. I have no idea why?

Why is the average of the new series is close to 1/3? Any particular theorem/law?

Thanks.

SAK

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, both uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, then the mean of $|X-Y|$ is
$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 |x - y|\ dx\ dy = 2 \int_0^1 \int_0^y (y-x)\ dx \ dy 
= \dfrac{1}{3}$$

Comment: Thank you very much Prof Israel for your quick reply. Can you please provide me with the quick reference to how the left side equals to 2 times...?